# Linq expression to filter an a list of entity's collection, and maintain list of entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

Lets say we have:

```
public class Foo
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Bar> { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public virtual Foo { get; set; }
    public long FooId  { get; set; }
}
```

Our data may look something like this: (assume `List<Foo>`)

```
// Forget the syntax, just to demonstrate data
foo[0] = new Foo{ Id = 1, Name = "A", Bar = { collection of Bars with Ages over 10 }};
foo[1] = new Foo{ Id = 2, Name = "B", Bar = { collection of Bars with Ages over 20 }};
foo[2] = new Foo{ Id = 3, Name = "C", Bar = { collection of Bars with Ages under 10 }};
```

Now, lets say I wanted all those `Foo`s but with their `Bar`s only including a `Bar` with an age between 5-25.

For something like this, I would work in reverse and get all Bars, then get all associated Foos to those bars, and re-map the Bars back to Foo. Seems overly complicated than it should be.

To be more clear - **All Foos with only their Bars with ages between 5 and 25** :)

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Your question is kind of unclear--do you want all `Foo`s with only their `Bar`s with ages between 5 and 25 or do you want only the `Foo`s that have `Bar`s with ages between 5 and 25?

Comment: One way, not suggested yet, is to implement an extension method on Foo with a declaration somewhat like: `GetBarsBetween(int lower, int upper);` and simply use this extenion method to do the filtering and retrieving of the correct bars within a Foo. Then you can simply select all Foo's `where foo.GetBarsBetween(5, 25).Any()`. This doesn't require any additional memomry allocation or restructuring of your current objects. Two disadvantages, you can't simply use existing code to work with the filtered bars and compute time is somewhat higher.

Comment: Unfortunately compute time I dont' have. This is just a simple look into what is a more complex problem. I have millions of Foos and millions of Bars, and doing look ups on columns that aren't indexed. Yikes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to select all `Foo`'s and only their `Bar`'s between the age of 5 and 25:

```
var results = 
    from f in db.Foos
    select new
    {
        f.Id,
        f.Name,
        Bars = f.Bars.Where(b => b.Age >= 5 && b.Age <= 25)
    };
```

This will produce an anonymous type as a result. If you need to create a named type (for example if you need to return the result from a function as a `List<T>`) you should probably create a simple named type for this result set:

```
public class FooWithFilteredBarResult // replace with whatever name you like
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Bar> { get; set; }
}


List<FooWithFilteredBarResult> results = 
    (from f in db.Foos
     select new FooWithFilteredBarResult 
     {
         Id = f.Id,
         Name = f.Name,
         Bars = f.Bars.Where(b => b.Age >= 5 && b.Age <= 25)
     })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: `let` carries a pretty sizable performance hit in linq to objects, just heads up.

Comment: The second answer to your answers is what I'm looking for. Is there a way to bypass having to specify all of the properties of Foo, instead just "auto-select" them and put the conditional on the Bars?

Comment: @Josh No, unfortunately there isn't, although you could always try to filter them later, e.g. as you're evaluating the results. Also you only need to specify the properties of `Foo` that you need. If there are 50 other properties you don't care about, you can leave those out.

Comment: Hm, so I would've gone with this but can't seem to pull it off since the second answer uses an anonymous type. So instead of a `List<Account>`, its `List<Anonymous#6>`.

Comment: And if I change it to `new Foo` it complains that it cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: @Josh you may want to create a named type that just represents this result set. That way you can use it as a return type / parameter type etc.

Comment: That's what I figured I had to do, I was hoping I didn't have to do that. I don't get why I'd need to though? I'm just returning it into a JsonResult anyway, where anonymous types may roam free.

Comment: @Josh Well you won't have create a named type to if you can manage to pass the result around without ever referring to it by name. Generic methods can help a lot here, but without seeing more of your code, I wouldn't be able to offer any specific advice. That would probably need to be a different question, anyway.

Comment: Well, Im just passing it into a JsonResult. I pass Anonymous types into it all the time.

Comment: @Josh Then I'm afraid I don't see the issue. `var result = ...; return this.Json(result);` should be just fine. You said you "can't pull it off", why not? Are there any errors?

Comment: Yes, "cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query"

Comment: +1 This must be the answer. It definitely makes sense to me, so I'm sure I'm doing something else wrong, which, like you said, should be another question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Josh I thought you said that was only when you tried to do `new Foo`. If you use anonymous types (and you don't do anything else too complicated) you *should* be okay. But yes, feel free to post that as another question and maybe I or someone else can figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
var r = Foos.Select(x => new Foo()
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Bars = x.Bars.Where(y => y.Age <= 25 && y.Age >= 5).ToList()
        });
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as @pswg option#2 answer, but it doesn't let me create a new Foo? It says the entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: @Josh it seems we submitted at the same time. Hmm..i didn't know you were talking about filtering records via EF. lemme think about it.

Answer (score 1):

This will also only select unique Foo's.

```
bars.Where(b => b.Age >= 5 && b.Age <= 25).GroupBy(b => b.FooId).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault().Foo).ToList();
```

Comment: I get the GroupBy. Why the Select/FirstOrDefault?

Comment: To select only the distinct Foo's, otherwise you might end up with repeats according to the question and structure.

Comment: That seems to return Bars?